# jQuery Ajax html response wait to remove old content when add to html()

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've searched in many topics but couldn't find an answer to this. Don't know if I'm doing in a wrong way, cause I'm new to ajax.

I have a `<div>` which I feed from an ajax response from PHP on a `<select>` on change.

But every time I select another `<option>` and it feeds the div again with new content, it first removes the current content, an that area gets blank, and after a second or so it adds the new content. I would like to find a way to make it switch from the current content to the new at the same time seamlessly, without "refreshing" the div before new content arrives.

```
function countrySelect() {
        countries = $('#countries-list option:selected').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://127.0.0.1/newtemplate/for-students/test/",
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            data: {countries:countries},
            dataType: 'html',
            beforeSend: function() {
                //loading state while waiting for data
                $("#uni-results").html('<div class="fetchLoading"><i class="fas fa-circle-notch fa-spin" style="font-size:2rem"></i></div>');
            },
            success: function(response){                 
                $("#uni-results").html(response);

                //if there are no results, display a warning
                if( !$.trim( $('#uni-results').html() ).length ) { 
                    $('#uni-results').html("no results found");
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you're wiping out your `uni-results` element immediately by replacing its contents with your loading message. Maybe just append instead:

```
beforeSend: function() {
    //loading state while waiting for data
    $("#uni-results").append('<div class="fetchLoading"><i class="fas fa-circle-notch fa-spin" style="font-size:2rem"></i></div>');
},
```

Protip: it's better practice to show your 'no results' message based on the response data, not what's in the page. Just check array length or whatever.